# Python look is failing and I dont know why: IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, loops, index-error

I created a brute force IR blaster for LIRC, but my loop that loops through the commands kept throwing an index failure, any ideas:

It is on line 48, the coms in comfile loop:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I have no idea why it won't loop and then go to the next file.

```
import os
import shutil
import subprocess
import time
# Using readline() 
count = 0
#os.remove("list.list")
os.system("touch /home/pi/com.list")
os.system("touch /home/pi/list.list")
os.system("systemctl start lircd")
for filename in os.listdir('confs'):
    currconf = "/home/pi/confs/" + filename
    print "**********start*******"
    print "1. ", filename
    #print "2. ", currconf
    #os.system("systemctl stop lircd")
    #subprocess.call('systemctl stop lircd', shell=True)
    shutil.move(currconf, "/etc/lirc/lircd.conf")


    subprocess.call('systemctl reset-failed lircd', shell=True)
    subprocess.call('systemctl restart lircd', shell=True)
    time.sleep(1)
    subprocess.call('systemctl status lircd | tail -3', shell=True)
   # os.system("systemctl start lircd")
   # irlist  = ""
    #print "3. ", irlist
    os.remove("/home/pi/list.list")
    os.remove("/home/pi/com.list")
    os.system('irsend list \"\" \"\" >> /home/pi/list.list')



    qbfile = open("/home/pi/list.list", "r")

    for aline in qbfile:
        values = aline.split()  
        print(values[0])

        rname = values[0].strip('\n')
        print "2. rname", rname
        comlist = 'irsend list ' + rname + ' \"\" >> /home/pi/com.list'
        print "3. comlist", comlist
        os.system(comlist)
        comfile = open("/home/pi/com.list", "r")
        for coms in comfile:
            comvalues = coms.split()  
            comand = comvalues[1]#.strip('\n')
            cmd =  "irsend SEND_ONCE " + rname + " " + comand
            print "4. cmd ", cmd
            time.sleep(.001)
            os.system(cmd)
    print "**********end*******"
```

Comment: Please reduce your example to a [mcve], and include the traceback in your question.

Comment: We don't know what line 48 is (I'm not going to count); the line `for coms in comfile:` will certainly not result in an `IndexError`.

Comment: You have a `print(values[0])` "debugging" call. Why not add similar ones for `coms` and `comvalues`, before you use any of those variables?

Comment: Sorry, didn't know if doesnt list line numbers.

Comment: When posting a question about code that produces an Exception, always include the complete Traceback - copy and paste it then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`)
.. [Catch the error](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and inspect/print relevant data in the except suite. .. `comand = comvalues[1]` - `comvalues` must have less than 2 items/things.

Comment: error on comvalues does not have 2 or more member, you need to check coms and comvalues as 0 0 said.

Answer (score -1):

Added an

```
If comsvalue:
```

And that filtered out the null values and let it continue.

Comment: Where to add that line?

Comment: I think you mean `comvalues` instead? What if `comvalues` is a non-empty string, but it does not contain any whitespace?